# Type 'any View' cannot conform to 'View' on protocol with generics

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, generics, swiftui

I'm using a protocol to define an override to the default `View` protocol to create some templated views in my app. They will all share the same `CalculationComponent` view for the bulk of the layout but then will implement different buttons / controls that are passed through with a `@ViewBuilder` which uses generics.

The issue I'm having is that when defining my protocol body, the generic type is throwing an error where `Type 'any View' cannot conform to 'View'`. I think this has directly to do with the `<Content: View>` part on `CalculationComponent`

**CalculationComponent.swift**

```swift
struct CalculationComponent<Content: View>: View {
    @Binding var mainCalculation: String
    @Binding var secondaryCalculation: String
    @ViewBuilder var content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        // Template UI here

        content()
    }
}
```

**CalculationView.swift**

```swift
protocol CalculationView: View {
    var mainCalculation: String { get set }
    var secondaryCalculation: String { get set}
    var body: CalculationComponent<View> { get } // Type 'any View' cannot conform to 'View'
}
```

**CalculatorView.swift**

```swift
struct CalculatorView: CalculationView {
    @State internal var mainCalculation: String = ""
    @State internal var secondaryCalculation: String = ""
    
    var body: CalculationComponent {
        CalculationComponent(
            mainCalculation: $mainCalculation,  
            secondaryCalculation: $secondaryCalculation
        ) {
            Text("Buttons and view content here")
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I had a much less sophisticated problem/solution for which I used this question. Gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/drosenstark/d90815b9c3ba83a90dbb4bd65a8d70ef). 

I'm sure I'll come back here with Google and wanted to leave a note ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a specialised version of the `View` protocol, where `Body` is `CalculationComponent<some View>`, and you don't want to write explicitly what "`some View`" is when conforming to the protocol, plus some other requirements.

You can add an associated type to `CalculationView`,

```
protocol CalculationView: View {
    associatedtype Content: View
    
    var mainCalculation: String { get set }
    var secondaryCalculation: String { get set}
    var body: CalculationComponent<Content> { get } // Type 'any View' cannot conform to 'View'
}
```

and then say `CalculationComponent<some View>` when conforming to the protocol:

```
struct CropFactorCalculatorView: CalculationView {
    
    @State internal var mainCalculation: String = ""
    @State internal var secondaryCalculation: String = ""
    
    var body: CalculationComponent<some View> {
        CalculationComponent(
            mainCalculation: $mainCalculation,
            secondaryCalculation: $secondaryCalculation
        ) {
            VStack {
                Text("Some Text")
                Text("Some Other Text")
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: That works! Can you explain why I can't pass just `View` to the generic of `CalculationComponent`? Why does it have to be first defined as an `associatedtype`?

Comment: @JoeScotto See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself). It would have worked if `View` didn't have the `Body` associated type requirement. It does have this associated type requirement, so `View` does not conform to `View`, and cannot be used to satisfy the `Content: View` constraint. After all, what is the `Body` type for `View`? You tell me!

Comment: I think I understand it now... basically `associatedtype Content: View` is saying that `Content` must be something that conforms to `View`. You can't just use View because that itself is a protocol and doesn't conform to anything therefore you must specify something that conforms to `View`. Does that sound about right?

Comment: @JoeScotto Yes. `View` doesn't conform to `View`.